# Unable to find version '6.9.5.0' of package 'MySql.Data.Entity.EF6'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, nuget-package-restore

When I try to build my ASP.NET MVC4 application I get the following error:
**Unable to find version '6.9.5.0' of package 'MySql.Data.Entity.EF6'.**

To my knowledge all packages are up to date. I have MySQL.Data, MySQL.Data.Entity, MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6, MySQL.Web (all versions 6.9.5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum you will need a reference to the `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6` assembly in your application's *\bin\* folder. If your list of installed packages is indeed complete, you may also require **MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.1** and **MySQL Connector/Net**.

Any search engine could get you links for these; I've found an excellent set of step-by-step instructions on the MySql forums at [How to start using Entity Framework 6 with MySQL databases](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264).

Comment: It was some kind of bug with VisualStudio-2013. Finally the problem resolved after I removed the entry for MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 from Packages.config.